# playing different audio sources simultaneously (VLC, youtube...)?

Tags: sound, vlc

I am using Ubuntu Studio 22.04.

I would like to use different audio sources simultaneously, e.g. VLC to play mp3 and Youtube in a browser, or two instances of VLC... with all audio sources sent to the same output (e.g. a jack-output or HDMI or USB)...
But it seems that, as soon as I start (e.g.) VLC, then audio will exclusively be played from that source, and other audio sources will be blocked.

Am I missing something ?!

Comment: I don't know if you're missing something, but for me this works out of the box on UbuntuStudio 22.04.

Comment: I also have no issues with an *out of the box* system with all supported releases...  Note: you're without many specifics, as for example I don't use the *low-latency* kernel which is less flexible (*but better for many audio/video-creation tasks; but you're talking about playback and not creation*).  Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS was also a LTS release, thus has two kernel stack choices... you may not be using the best choice for your *unstated* release for example (*your installation media dictates the kernel stack being used, though it can be changed post-install*)